# Contar registros con foreach PHP

Tags: php, html

Bueno es bastante sencillo supongo, pero el punto es que quiero contar los registros de la base de datos, en este caso tengo 2 en la BD, y al poner el `foreach` y verlo en la tabla me muestra los 2 registros pero con el numero 2, cuando debería ser 1,2,3,4.. consecutivo... en este ejemplo me los deberia de mostrar 1,2..

La tabla con 2 registros

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El foreach en PHP : /

```
foreach($usuarios as $key => $value){

   echo '<tr>
        <td>'.count($usuarios).'</td>
        <td>'.$value["nombres"].'</td>
        <td>'.$value["apellidos"].'</td>
        <td>'.$value["correo"].'</td>
        <td>'.$value["usuario"].'</td>';
```

Comment: es que el uso del count, siempre te traera la sumatoria de todas la filas, en este caso siempre te traera el numero 2

Comment: tiene algun `id` autoincrementable o algo asi ? si no es asi te toca con un variable mormal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

una manera es asi:

```
//variable que almacenara los valores en cada ciclo
$contador=1;
foreach($usuarios as $key => $value){

    echo '<tr>
  <td>'.$contador.'</td>
  <td>'.$value["nombres"].'</td>
  <td>'.$value["apellidos"].'</td>
  <td>'.$value["correo"].'</td>
  <td>'.$value["usuario"].'</td>';

  //se incrementa el valor para que el proximo ciclo valga uno mas
  $contador= $contador + 1;
```

espero te sirva... me cuentas!

Comment: Fue más fácil definir la variable y que corra el ciclo, gracias :)

Comment: Si, bro me alegro "Tocallo"

Answer (score 1):

Si, es bastante sencillo, puedes obtener el index del bucle de la siguiente manera:

```
 <?php
 foreach($array as $key => $item){
  echo $key . ":" . $item . "<br>";
}
?>
```

Otra opcion es que definas una variable incrementable, y solo la muestras donde necesites:

```
$i=0;
foreach ($rows as $key => $row) { 
echo $row['id']; 
echo $row['firstname']; 
echo $row['lastname']; 
echo $i;
$i++;
}
```

Espero haberte ayudado. Suerte!

Answer (score 1):

si es un array indexado esto serviria perfecto porque la variable `$key` lleva el indice

```
foreach($usuarios as $key => $value){    
                  echo '<tr>
                <td>'.$key+1.'</td>
```